# How to create rounded corners in electron browserWindow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, window, electron

Ive searched everywhere on how to make the corners rounded of my browserWindow.

How can I achieve rounded corners?

I've tried making it transparent. But nothing works.

Hers my code:

```js
/**
 * we need to keep a global reference of the window object. If we don't, the
 * window will be closed automatically when the js object is garbage collected
 */
let win

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1800,
    height: 1000,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    icon: __dirname + 'icon.png'
  })
  
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', function () {
    /**
     * Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows in an
     * array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time when you
     * should delete the corresponding element.
     */
    win = null
  })
}
```

Comment: `frame: false, radii: [5,5,5,5]` is what I have read.

Comment: where is this added? @scoopzilla

Comment: @scoopzilla it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

For transparency try using the opacity property. The range is from 0 to 1

Answer (score -1):

```
function createWindow () {
   // Create the browser window.
   win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1800,
      height: 1000,
      frame: false,
      radii: [5,5,5,5],
      transparent: true,
      icon: __dirname + 'icon.png'
})
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything. As I'm trying to make the corners rounded. It's still not rounded.

Comment: I must be missing something then. Sorry :(